# Resource object with key not found, but the resource file is there

Tags: resource-files, display-form, resources

I am creating a custom display form(.aspx) and in it I must have multilanguage support. I added a resource file in the Resourses mapped folder, added data to it and deployed.

An error occured: `The resource object with key '<some key>' was not found.`

I looked it up and saw that this problem occurs when the *.resx file is not deployed to the `App_GlobalResources` folder.

Now I looked to find where the file had been deployed to and I found it in both `...VirtualDirectories\Project\App_GlobalResources` and `...Web Server Extensions\14\Resources` so the file is there and it should be accessable. I found many solutions(mark it as global resource in the package file; put it in a module, add some settings and deploy;) none of them worked for me.

All the names are correct. Things like iisreset also didn't work.

This is what I added in the display form: `<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Res, Oil%>" />`

Any ideas?

Comment: Check whether the resource file has the key "Oil".

Comment: It is. That was the first thing I checked

Comment: Check whether "Res" is the filename of resource file.Check the UI language and see whether file exists for that language

Comment: All the names are correct.

Comment: Can you post the file names ie the main resource file name and file names in different languages and also the "Oil" key tag

Comment: IISRESET can be the key here (maybee even reset of SP Timer v4). Caching of resource files is often quite hard

Comment: It's working now. I made an iisreset again and restarted the Timer process.

Comment: @RobertLindgren - I've got the same problem again. This time IISRESET and restarting the Timer process didn't work(tried a couple of times). The weird part is that most of the resources are there and working. Only fiew are missing. Again all the names and keys are spelled correctly. All the files in the folders 'App_GlobalResources' and '../14/Resources' are up to date.

Comment: Let me guess, your new ones are not there, but the old ones are? Classic caching issue

Comment: Exactly, but how do I fix it, even IISRESET does not work.